# Confusing error, out of memory and undefined reference with SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox in Code Blocks

Tags: c++, sdl, codeblocks, sdl-2

So I am starting with Code Blocks and was following a tutorial online, I made an empty project that had one file.

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>


//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //The window we'll be rendering to
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;

    //The surface contained by the window
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

    //Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    }
    else
    {
        //Create window
        window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if( window == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        }
        else
        {
            //Get window surface
            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( window );

            //Fill the surface white
            SDL_FillRect( screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB( screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );

            //Update the surface
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );

            //Wait two seconds
            SDL_Delay( 2000 );
        }
    }

    //Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Linker Settings:

```
-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

And I get this error,

```
||=== Build: Debug in Yeet (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
D:\Coding\addons\lib\x86\SDL2main.lib(Win32\Release\SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_OutOfMemory]+0xf)||undefined reference to `SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

I'm not sure if this is a memory error, or an undefined reference error if it is a memory error I would not know why since other bigger programs have had enough memory, and the undefined reference is erroring on a piece of code that seems to not be in my code...
Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: It clearly says "undefined reference", why would it be anything to do with memory? I don't understand why you are asking if an error that says "undefined reference" is an undefined reference error or not.

Comment: On line 2 of the error it says at the middle "(.text[_OutOfMemory]+0xf)"

Comment: That is a function name inside SDL2main. Nothing particularly interesting about it, but it wants to raise message box via SDL2 function, which linker can't find. Either your SDL2 library is very old (while SDL2main isn't) and don't have that function yet, or you don't link with SDL2 (for any reason, from omitting it from library list to attempting to pull library for wrong CPU architecture). Can you show full build log with invoked commands and their output, not just last error? Also your last mesage says "2 errors", can we see the other one?

Comment: We need to see the complete build log.

Comment: That is the whole build log, really. I don't know why it says two errors.

Comment: Wait. It says `D:\Coding\addons\lib\x86\SDL2main.lib`, and libraries for MinGW are supposed to have `.a` extension. Did you by any chance downloaded the version for MSVC?

Comment: @EricBromstead judging by format of the messages, it is what codeblocks call "build messages". What we asked for is a "build log", preferably after "build->rebuild" menu entry.

Comment: Ok, I think I might have gotten the wrong file, one for MSVS... So yeah I'm going to redownload all of the files and try again.

Comment: Yeah redownloading the correct libraries actually worked! Apparently, I was using the MSVS files. say thank you HolyBlackCat :)

Answer (score 1):

So yeah I was using the wrong libraries, so if anyone else is having a problem make sure you're downloading the correct files for your IDE. Thank you HolyBlackCat :)